# Multiple web frameworks in single AWS instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is an infrastructure design question. Is it better to:

1. Run multiple web frameworks on a single AWS instance?
2. Run each framework in separate AWS instances?

Here are the web frameworks used:

- Backend: `Django + PostgreSQL`
- Frontend: `NodeJS`
- Forum: `Ruby on Rails + PostgreSQL`

Option 1 pros:

- No need to worry about AWS instance type (just use a powerful one)
- Easy to maintain when everything is in one place, only 1 instance

Option 2 pros:

- Better allocation of AWS resources depending on load (backend / frontend / forum). Easier to scale?

I am not sure what's the better option. Would love to hear your experience and opinion on this. Thanks.

Comment: I think option 1 is better. If you choose option 2 then it also issues for an extra charge where you can only use one instance to run every framework.

Comment: You may want to consider Docker on ECS. It sounds like a good use case for Docker containers

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of people putting all of this inside a single AMI, spinning them up behind an ELB and running it in production.

Is it advised? Not really.

The issue with this is pretty much what you stated, each has variable resource requirements (besides NodeJS) and you will be overloading EC2 instances quickly with any type of load; when they aren't seeing load you will be burning $$$ by having a powerful enough instance (for the expected load) running 24/7.

In terms of a close but slightly better option, putting each of these frameworks inside their own Docker container allows them to run alongside each other on the same instance but in a segregated way. Once they are in Docker, you might as well run them in ECS or EKS on Fargate.

In terms of the "AWS Best Practice" route, and wearing my **Solution Architect** hat, I would recommend this:

- `NodeJS` is put into S3, with CloudFront in front of it.
- `Python(Django)` is moved to Lambda or Lambda EDGE.
- `PostgreSQL` is moved to RDS, or better yet - DynamoDB.

The advantage to this is cost and scalability. S3 scales infinitely and is highly available and dirt cheap. Lambda is event-based so you are into "pay per usage" rather than "pay per hour". RDS is a $ sink but it takes care of backups and makes running a DB a simple task. DynamoDB is a "pay per usage" service and would make your entire stack significantly cheaper if you can pull it off.